# Search YouTube and exclude certain terms from the video's title?

Tags: youtube, search

How can I search YouTube and exclude certain terms from the video's title? For instance, I want to search for "glass" but exclude videos with "Google" in the title.

I'd like to stress that I want to exclude terms ONLY from the title of the video. Searching ONLY the title can be done with `allintitle:TERM`, but apparently `-allintitle:TERM` does not work to exclude terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "-exclude_this_text" to search. It worked for me.

Searching for "mvc *-asp*" resulted in all the MVC videos, excluding those relating to ASP.

Searching for films I used *-2014* to exclude 2014 from title and that also worked example: *film full sifi -2014*.

Comment: I think a single `-` should suffice in your searches. That's the `NOT` operator for Google searches.